# Looking for ways and experiences to improve Keras model accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, regression

I am an electrical engineer and I am looking for a solution to calculate the DC current of a permanent synchronous motor. So I decided to check the ANN solutions with Keras and so on.Long story short, I'll show you a screenshot of some measured [signals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7wA6.png).

The first 5 signals are the measured signals. The last one is the DC current, which I will estimate. Here the value was recorded with the help of a current clamp. Okay, I started building a model in Python and tried some things that I assume will increase the accuracy of the model. But after all that, I am not getting that good results from the model and my hope is that maybe I am choosing wrong parameters or not an ideal model for this purpose.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Import input (x) and output (y) data, and asign these to df1 and df1
df = pd.read_csv('train_data.csv')
df = df[['rpm','iq','uq','udc','idc']]
X = df[df.columns[:-1]]
Y = df.idc

plt.figure()
sns.heatmap(df.corr(),annot=True)
plt.show()

# Split the data into input (x) training and testing data, and ouput (y) training and testing data, 
# with training data being 80% of the data, and testing data being the remaining 20% of the data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2)#, shuffle=True)

# Scale both training and testing input data
X_train = preprocessing.maxabs_scale(X_train)
X_test = preprocessing.maxabs_scale(X_test)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, input_shape=(4,)))
model.add(Dense(4, input_shape=(4,)))
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(4,)))

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="msle", metrics=['mean_squared_logarithmic_error','accuracy'])

# Pass several parameters to 'EarlyStopping' function and assign it to 'earlystopper'
earlystopper = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=15, verbose=1, mode='auto')

model.summary()
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 2000, validation_split = 0.3, verbose = 2, callbacks = [earlystopper])

# Runs model (the one with the activation function, although this doesn't really matter as they perform the same) 
# with its current weights on the training and testing data
y_train_pred = model.predict(X_train)
y_test_pred = model.predict(X_test)

# Calculates and prints r2 score of training and testing data
print("The R2 score on the Train set is:\t{:0.3f}".format(r2_score(y_train, y_train_pred)))
print("The R2 score on the Test set is:\t{:0.3f}".format(r2_score(y_test, y_test_pred)))

df = pd.read_csv('test_two_data.csv')
df = df[['rpm','iq','uq','udc','idc']]
X = df[df.columns[:-1]]
Y = df.idc
X_validate = preprocessing.maxabs_scale(X)

y_pred = model.predict(X_validate)

plt.plot(Y)
plt.plot(y_pred)
plt.show()

(weight_0,bias_0) = model.layers[0].get_weights()
(weight_1,bias_1) = model.layers[1].get_weights()
```

One limitation is that I can't use LSTM layers or other complex algorithms because I need to implement the trained model in a microcontroller on a motor application later.

I guess you could find some words for me to make my model a little better in accuracy.

At the end here is a figure where I show you the worse prediction performance. Orange is the prediction and blue is the measured [current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDh84.png).

The [training dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuQjk.png) was this one.

The correlation between the individual values can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGi0q.png). Since the values of id and ud have no correlation to idc, I decided to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

1. The most important thing to keep in mind when trying to improve the accuracy of the model is **ALWAYS Normalise** the input data which basically means rescaling real-valued numeric attributes into the range 0 and 1. I am not able to understand the way you are providing the training data to the model. Could you please explain that. It would be better in understanding and identifying the scope of higher accuracy.
2. Now if we talk about parameters, I would suggest you the addition of a Tuning Algorithm for the parameters to get the optimized value of each parameter.
   It is always a good parctice to include hidden layers which could provide better feature extract.

Comment: Regarding point 1:
Ive tried MinMaxScaler or as shown in the code above, the MaxAbsScaler. But in principle the used scaler is a higher effort for the implementation on the microcontroller. Therefore I have already tried to divide the parameters by their physical range of values. Also this gave results with no good accuracy. The training data are the features 'rpm','iq','uq','udc','idc'. They are divided into X-values ('rpm','iq','uq','udc') and Y-values ('idc').

Comment: Regarding 2:
An interesting point. Could you possibly explain how to proceed with a tuning of the
of the parameters?

I have already tried to add several hidden layers. The accuracy was not significantly improved. I would also like to avoid the use of very many layers, because it would require
a high computational effort on the microcontroller.